# Using Spark createDataFrame to cut DAG

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I currently have a pipeline architecture in a spark project with processes (A, B, C, D) where the output of process A is the input to process B, and the output of process B is the input to process C, etc... A process can contain one or more spark sql queries, and outputs a cached dataframe. This is a linear pipeline, so process C will only use the output of process B, and not the output of process A.

As you might imagine, all this caching takes up a lot of memory, especially on large datasets. When on process C, I no longer need the output of process A, just the output from process B. Normally with spark if I uncache the output of process A, then the output of process B also gets uncached, which I need in process C. So to handle this I do the following:

```
val new_output = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(output.rdd, output.schema)

new_output.createOrReplaceTempView("new_output")
spark.sql("CACHE TABLE new_output")

inputDf.unpersist(true)

return new_output
```

When I do this, it basically cuts the dag, so I can uncache the input dataframes. When I do an explain on the new_output dataframe it looks like this:

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
LogicalRDD [a#168], false
```

**Question:** I am trying to see if this approach could cause issues down the line related to resiliency with spark, or in other ways.

I am fully aware I could use spark checkpointing to insert checkpoints into the DAG. With the above approach, I do not have to spend time writing data to disk / external storage, like a checkpoint would.
I would like to keep this all in the same spark application and persist the data in memory between processes.

**Update1:** Added more code to show the order of caching and uncaching. Using eager caching so the new_output dag is executed and stored in memory so the inputDf can be uncached.

Comment: Nice question but logical it is not possible unless we store result in separate RRD .

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you mean. I added some more code to show how things are being cached and uncached. Is that what you were referring to?